# Video playback how to zoom so the entire video picture is displayed on the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

I'm using MPMoviePlaybackController to play movies on my iPhone app.  Everything works fine, except the full screen toggle bottom basically does nothing.  When I toggle it, the picture grows slightly.

I want it to behave like every other app that plays videos on the iphone.  When you toggle the full screen button, the picture is zooomed, so aspect ratio is maintained, but you just end up losing part of the picture, since it's off screen.

What is the purpose of the full screen toggle if it doesn't actually show the video full screen?

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your raw video source? If your raw video is already pre-matted (ie, has black bars within the file itself) you'll see the kind of thing you describe.

Comment: It is an mp4 movie trailer.  What I don't understand is, for example if I download a movie to my phone from itunes, let's say it is in 2.40:1 aspect ratio. When I play it on my phone using the iphone video player, I obviously see black bars above, and below the picture - this is the only way to display the entire picture whil maintaining aspect ratio - I get that.  However, I can choose to toggle the fullscreen button, and then the video picture *will* take up the entire screen in a zoomed fashion.  That's all I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about MPMoviePlayerController Class, it should do the necessary.

anyways you can use the below notifications to manually rezize the size of window, use scalingMode of the property and set it to any of the below scaling mode
typedef enum {
   MPMovieScalingModeNone,
   MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit,
   MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill,
   MPMovieScalingModeFill
} MPMovieScalingMode;

Whenever the movie player enters or exits full-screen mode, it posts appropriate notifications to reflect the change. For example, upon entering full-screen mode, it posts MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification and MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification notifications. Upon exiting from full-screen mode, it posts MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification and MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification notifications.